# Save comment in database (magento2)?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

**I'm creating text box in `sales->order->create new order admin form.`
How to save text box value in table.In sales table ,created column name "custom_comment"...**

Comment: can you please explain in bit detail what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: In sales->order->create new order admin form.I have create text box for order comments.I want save order comment in sales_order_grid table.Also created order_comment is column name in sales_order_grid table.

Comment: It is clear now?